# Caching HTML in variables

Tags: php, html

I've been mulling over the idea of caching html in variable. I'm using PHP, in my functions include I have declared a variable. In the site pages I test the variable to see if it is empty, if so I call a function and populate the variable, or dump it into the page.

In the testing I've carried out it works as expected. I guess my question is, is it a good idea? What are the potential problems with this as an approach?

Regards

Comment: Can you show what you're doing?

Comment: Rather than the problems can you tell us why you want to do this and what advantage it gives?

Comment: last time when i checked that was the purpose of variables, to hold `things`.

Comment: @Twisted1919, little snarky, eh?

Comment: My intention is to store the navigation. The site has a database behind it and as the navigation isn't not going to change very often it seemed a good idea to cut out the repeated calls to the database and while I'm grabbing the main menu I can get the nav for the footer. As I say, in the functions include file I create an empty variable and in the menu file I test to see if the variable is empty, if it is I populate it.

I was wondering if there were any common gotta's with this approach.

@Twisted1919, that's what I thought, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The cons** for this method are related to dynamic content that need to change based on the current user visiting. If you can identify portions of your Markup that are expensive to generate but are quite static regarding users visiting the site, you can do this.

But you need to put some thought into your page structure. And to cache Markup, you use `output buffering` :) obviously and `database transients` I presume, unless you want to do it in memory.

**Also make sure it's worth caching markup and it's not easier caching data structures**. Like arrays, objects that are generated from DB and are expensive to rebuild. Caching data structures makes your caching Markup agnostic and you can easily restyle your site without having to invalidate your entire cache.

**PS**: **@Bart**, *I rolled my own framework and it's not an inferior product :) Stop being a user and start being a developer.* **Experiment, learn, build from scratch, get near the metal, see sparks flying, feel the burn.**

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the positive response.

Answer (score 1):

Of course caching is a good idea.  Lots of people use an in-memory store, like Memcached or APC cache.

The major drawback is it usually takes a good plan for invalidating caches when the information is no longer up-to-date.  It's also a decent indicator you might be prematurely optimizing (or making up for poor-performing code without fixing it).

In your particular case, you might be better off using output buffering or loading views.  Most people wouldn't consider this "caching."

Answer (score 0):

No it is not a good idea. Read into [MVC: model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There are many decent frameworks out there. Get to know them and use them. Rolling your own will most probably create an inferior product.

Good luck!

Comment: Sometimes it clearly is a good idea to cache html in a variable, e.g if loading the html & populating with data involves expensive calls to the database, this will increase load time. Cached output can counter this in some circumstances

Comment: I think it's a case of horses for course. This is a very small project, etc, etc...